# Using boost::numeric::odeint inside the class

Tags: c++, oop, boost, ode

For a simulation, I'm using boost::numeric::odeint but I'm having a problem. I'm using the integrate function inside a method of one of my classes and I'm having the error of "no matching function for call to integrate". To be more clear, here is a compressed version of my code:

```
#include "MotionGeneration.h"
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

typedef boost::array< double , 10 > state_type;

MotionGeneration::MotionGeneration(some_data) {
     //My constructor.
     //some_data assignment.
}

MotionGeneration::~MotionGeneration() {

}

double MotionGeneration::getError(double time) {
   //error calculation.
}

void MotionGeneration::execute(){
    state_type init_conf = { 0, -1.5708, 0, 0, 0, -1.5708, 0, -1.5708, 0, 0.5};
    boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(motionScheme, init_conf, 0.0, 1.0, 0.05, plot);
}

void MotionGeneration::motionScheme(const state_type &q, state_type &q_dot, double t){
     //Some long code goes here. Also I have some calls to some methods of this class. for example:
     double err = getError(t);          
}

void MotionGeneration::plot(const state_type &q , const double t){
    //some data pfintf here.
}
```

Please note that none of my methods are static and as a matter of fact, I can not use static method. When I build the project, I have the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to `integrate(<unknown type>, state_type&, double, double, double, <unknown type>)'
```

I think it's a problem of having the system function as a class method but I don't know how to handle this situation.

Comment: Well one solution would be friend functions instead of member functions. Can't say it really works out for the best in the end if there's a better option, though.

Comment: @chris, interesting idea but it has some difficulties. For example, I have to send an instance of MotionGeneration class to the friend function and this might not be compatible with the integrate function.

Comment: @chris, I did it. In a very painful way :/
I convert the methods of integrator to static methods. And then rewrote almost the whole class from beginning.

Comment: It really is a shame. I would expect there to be a better way out there than that.

Comment: It is also very probable that it's my fault somehow :D
After I tackled the problem and start to test it, I've found it very powerful.

Answer (score 4):

odeint needs an

`operator()( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double dt )`

In your case, MotionGenerator does not have this operator, but you can bind the method motionScheme

```
#include <functional>
namespace pl = std::placeholders;

// ...

// not tested
void MotionGeneration::execute()
{
    state_type init_conf = { 0, -1.5708, 0, 0, 0, -1.5708, 0, -1.5708, 0, 0.5};
    boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(
        std::bind(&MotionGenerator::motionScheme, *this , pl::_1 , pl::_2 , pl::_3 ) , init_conf, 0.0, 1.0, 0.05, plot);
}
```

```

But,it would be easy to rename your method `motionScheme` to `operator()`, and simply pass `*this` to integrate.

Edit: You can also use `std::ref` to avoid copies of your instance of MotionGenerator:

```
void MotionGeneration::execute()
{
    state_type init_conf = { 0, -1.5708, 0, 0, 0, -1.5708, 0, -1.5708, 0, 0.5};
    boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(
        std::bind(&MotionGenerator::motionScheme, std::ref(*this) , pl::_1 , pl::_2 , pl::_3 ) , init_conf, 0.0, 1.0, 0.05, plot);
}
```

Comment: I got this working using `integrate_const( stepper , *this , a_state, a_time , end_time , time_step );`, it does the integration, but it seems that it doesn't actually change the state or rate properties of the class. Why is this? Does it work on some copy of the class?

Comment: Oops I forgot to use `std::ref(*this)`