# Using a boost::numeric::odeint stepper inside a complicated class

Tags: c++, class, scope, odeint

I have an extremely convoluted system of numerical rate equations, which are to be solved by the class `ElectronSolver`. The electron state is handled by a separate class `state_type`, not shown here.
A simplified template of the problem class appears as

ElectronSolver.h

```
class ElectronSolver {
public:
    ElectronSolver(const char* filename, ofstream& log);
    void solve();
    void print(const std::string& fname);
    std::vector<double> T; // Times, in fs
    std::vector<state_type> Y; // stores the state_t's
private:
    //                       steps, State,   value,  Derivative, Time,   Algebra
    adams_bashforth_moulton< 5, state_type, double, state_type, double, vector_space_algebra > abm;

    void set_initial_conditions();
    // Model parameters
    PhotonFlux pf;

    void sys(const state_type& s, state_type& sdot, const double t);
};
```

ElectronSolver.cpp

```
void ElectronSolver::set_initial_conditions(){
    // Set the initial T such that pulse peak occurs at T=0
    T[0] = -timespan/2;
    Y[0] = state_type(Store, num_elec_points);
    abm.initialize( sys, Y[0], T[0], dt ); // This line produces an error
}

void ElectronSolver::sys(const state_type& s, state_type& sdot, const double t){
    // complicated system modifying sdot
    sdot.flux += pf(t)*s.flux;
}
```

However, some research revealed why the marked line throws a compile error. 
As far as I can understand `sys` as declared here must be called "on a class", so cannot simply be passed as a reference. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976078/using-boostnumericodeint-inside-the-class) got around that by declaring `sys` as static, but that won't work here since I'm relying on calling other members of `ElectronSolver` in `sys`.

There is little concievable reason that I would need multiple instances of ElectronSolver, but I would like to leave the option there in case any code maintainers want to have two different electron models.

As far as I can tell, I have four options:

1. make everything `sys` needs `static` (less than desirable due to `ElectronSolver` inheriting from other classes, but doable)
2. Construct some kind of a wrapper for the `sys` function (possibly has a performance hit, and more to the point, I don't know how to do this)
3. Implement the ODE stepper myself to avoid the headaches of using `boost`.
4. ????

Which solution strikes the best bargain between
 - Performance (though the largest performance bottleneck is *probably* the time it takes `sys` to execute)
 - Code elegance
 - Modularity
?

Comment: Performance issues seem negligible here. As for "elegance", I would vote for `std::bind` (below), as it clearly exposes the intention behind its use: to call a function through a different interface the function was originally deigned to be called with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you want to continue using boost is a decision only you can make, but it's easy to create a wrapper with no performance hit.

You'll want to wrap `sys` in a lambda that captures `this`. This should not have a performance hit, as the lambda will be inlined when optimizations are turned on.

You would call it like this:

```cpp
abm.initialize(
    [this](const state_type& s, state_type& sdot, const double t) {
        this->sys(s, sdot, t);
    },
    Y[0],
    T[0],
    dt
);
```

The lambda is basically an implicit wrapper struct that holds a reference to `this` and defines an `operator()(const state_type& s, state_type& sdot, const double t)`.

I created an [example in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7veW6v) that shows this, simplifying and filling in your code where necessary for the example. If you change the optimization between `-O0` and `-O3` you can see the lambda code is stripped away and the inner method is fully inlined.

Another option is use `std::bind` to create a bare function out of the member function:

```cpp
abm.initialize(
    std::bind(&ElectronSolver::sys, std::ref(*this), _1, _2, _3),
    Y[0],
    T[0],
    dt
);
```

along with this elsewhere:

```cpp
#include <functional>
using namespace std::placeholders;
```

to get all the symbols into scope. `std::bind` creates a new function where the some arguments are already filled in. In this case the implicit first argument, the object itself, is filled in with a reference to `this`. The rest of the arguments are given special placeholders to indicate the new function will fill them in with its arguments. The `std::ref`, forces taking `this` by reference rather than by copy. This method will also have zero overhead.

Comment: > Whether or not you want to continue using boost is a decision only you can make  

What are good alternatives?

Comment: As the author said, writing your own ODE solver is always an alternative. Boost is often difficult to use, so sometimes it's not worth it if you only need a small bit of the functionality. As for ODE solvers, [this](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/de_solver_software_comparsion.pdf) is a good overview of many of them across languages. [Sundials](https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/sundials) (specifically CVODE) supports C++, but is written for C and acts like a C library.

Comment: For what it's worth, I did end up writing my own ODE stepper to avoid a boost dependency. However, this answer is excellent and would definitely have made me reconsider doing so if it had come earlier.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working :) If you think this is a good answer, consider accepting it.

Comment: The problem's been posed badly: it is not a minimum working example, one has to strip unnecessary details themselves. Then, one realizes that the actual problem has nothing to do with boost etc., but is "an instance" of a common problem found e.g. here: stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/… ("How can I pass a member function where a free function is expected?"). Then one concludes that the answer given here is excellent and much better than in the link above. Alas, with such a question title, it will pass unnoticed :-(

Comment: One more remark. The answer with lambda apparently works only because  `initialize` is a templated function and can accept both free functions and functors as its 1st argument.  If `initialize` had a C-like interface with fixed type of its arguments, lambda would work only if the capture was empty, which is not the case.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was ill-posed, but really how else could I have gone about it a priori? I don't know the conventions associated with `boost` and such, so I fell back on the guideline "Describe what you are trying to achieve with your code" rather than pretending to know more than I do.